# Canon LBP 2900B does not print anything after installation, but print completed message is displayed on Ubuntu LTS 16.04

Tags: printing, canon

I've got the printer installed and ready. However, once I issue a print command, either from properties or from other documents, the "job completed" message is displayed, but nothing gets printed. The job in queue empties itself after the message is displayed.What do I do to get the printer working?